# How to measure USB port real-world speed? and not USB device speed

Tags: linux, usb, speed, kubuntu

Using Kubuntu 22.04.1

At back of desktop computer there are two **blue** USB ports with Type-A connectors.

Theoretical speed command 1:

> lsusb -t
>
> Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, **20000M/x2**

Theoretical speed command 2:

> cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/speed
>
> **20000** = 20000 Mbps = 20 Gbps

No USB device I have operates at 20 Gbps.

How to measure USB port real-world speed? Not USB device speed

Reference: [USB 3.2 Speed Comparison & Real-world Performance](https://www.everythingusb.com/speed.html)

Answer (score 3):

`lsusb` returns the theoretical maximum speed of the **port**,
not of any device that is connected to it.

For how to measure real-world speed, see the post
[How do I find out USB Speed from a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162434/how-do-i-find-out-usb-speed-from-a-terminal/162462#162462)

Below is the
[answer by noffle](https://askubuntu.com/a/162462/963426) :

> The `pv` tool allows you to view the throughput of the data flowing
> through it. After installing the package, you could run a command like
> the following to see the write rate:
>
> ```
> $ cat /dev/zero | pv > /media/some_usb/tmp123
>
> 203.1MiB 0:00:02 [100.2MiB/s] [ <=>                   ]
> ```
>
> For reading, perform the opposite operation using the newly-created
> `tmp123` file:
>
> ```
> $ cat /media/some_usb/tmp123 | pv > /dev/null
> ```

Another idea was to use `gnome-disks` in terminal using its
GUI interface :
Click the disk you want to test -> Device Options ->
Benchmark Disk -> Start Benchmark.

See the linked post for more information.

Comment: Intead of using a temp file just use /dev/sdX  to read the raw block device (which also may avoid some caching issues).   Also, you can bypass cat by using **pv < /dev/sdX > /dev/null** Don't do this for the read test unless you are willing to repartition and reformat your disk afterwards.  Also, you need to run the test a while to mitigate caching effects.

Comment: pv 1.6.6 was installed this command below appears to be
device related ```cat /dev/zero | pv > /media/x/some_usb/file.txt``` 
but my interest was port related speed not device related speed. 
For example the Reference Link says ```20 Gbps``` theory and ```16 Gbps``` real world.  My USB port say ```20 Gbps``` theory.  How to measure USB port real-world speed? not device speed, not file speed.

Comment: Real-world speed must be measured with a real-world device, and will depend on the speed capability of the device. Otherwise, how would you define a real-world speed?

Comment: That's a good point, but how did they measure real-world ```16 Gbps``` = ```16000 Mbps```?  See web page ```USB 3.2 Speed Comparison & Real-world Performance```.  Was RAM involved?  Was it a dynamic RAM drive?

Comment: I see this in your link : "To illustrate how fast USB 3.2 Gen 2×1 (10Gbps) is in real-world scenarios, we compared the speed of five USB SSDs in the bar graph below". They used fast USB devices.